# Capturing Video Frame and then Exporting as Bitmap in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I have a web application where I play back video.

I am considering using the HTML5 `<video>` element and have determined it will allow me to meet all of my requirements except one: **allowing the user to take a snapshot of the current video frame and save it as a raster image format (i.e. JPG).**

For this requirement I have not found a solution, and any guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

To help answer the question here are more details. I will download the video files from a server via HTTP and then play them back in the browser. This will not be a video stream, but instead a download with playback starting after the file has been received. The video will be in the *MP4* format.

The solution only needs to run in IE 9. (Although naturally I would like the solution to be as cross-browser/platform as possible.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Capture the image to a `canvas` element:

```
var video  = document.getElementById(videoId);
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width  = video.videoWidth;
canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
```

Then use the [`toDataURL()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl) method to get the image:

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

Be aware that for all this to work [the video has to be from the same origin as the page](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements).

Comment: Interesting. Do you think using `canvas` might also work if the video was being rendered by a plugin like Silverlight? See related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372521/capturing-video-frame-and-then-exporting-as-bitmap-in-silverlight-4.

Comment: This is awesome! It really opens up a lot of possiblities beyond what I was thinking. Thanks.

Comment: @RickRoth The spec says explicitly that the argument to `drawImage` has to be either an HTMLImageElement, an HTMLCanvasElement, or an HTMLVideoElement - so I don't expect Silverlight would work.

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks again for the great solution though.

Comment: "video has to be from the same origin as the page". Then how does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25970950/1461424) work?

Comment: @Krumia As far as I can tell: it doesn't.

Comment: @robertc: hmm... interesting. It works for me and the OP. Must find out why.