# Take snapshot from a url based video file in a Javascript Metro Application

Tags: javascript, html5-video, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I've a few video files urls that my application plays, using the html video tag.

I would like to shows tiles of those videos with an snapshot/thumbnail of it.
I've been looking at the [Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) class and it seems it doesn't support urls.

How can I do this?.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing Video Frame and then Exporting as Bitmap in HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372501/capturing-video-frame-and-then-exporting-as-bitmap-in-html5)

Comment: If the video is *local*, you should be able to ask the OS to get a thumbnail of that video, but I suspect you want content from the inter-tubes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227213.aspx is the relevant API.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate because the video files I have are never stored physically.

Comment: Thanks @dhopton. Video files are streamed and it seems that that API is for locally stored files. Maybe I should use Windows.Storage.StorageFile.createStreamedFileFromUriAsync before calling the method you mentioned?

Comment: Don't think that'll help you'll have to resort to the method mentioned by robertc.

You could always just use real video tags, and keep them paused, rather than capturing thumbnails. Is there a reason you want to capture a specific thumbnail?

Comment: That would save my day but the client wants to be able to select himself which thumbnail to show from a list of 10-15 snapshots randomly taken.

Comment: According to Ming Xu from Microsoft, currently there's no easy way of doing this with JavaScript directly. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/ba0ad5c5-f9ac-40ca-a7ee-69f75a198282

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `getThumbnailAsync` parameters as needed to get what you want.

```
var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(function (storageFile) {
    if (storageFile) {

        storageFile.getThumbnailAsync(
            Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.musicView,
            100,
            Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailOptions.useCurrentScale).then(
                function (storageItemThumbnail) {
                // Add code to process thumbnail
                });

    } else {
        // No file
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that the file is streamed. It's not a physical file.