# Is it possible to grab an image from a video stream from an HTML5/Flash/iOS player?

Tags: ios, html, flash, video-streaming

Ok, the context here is that I have a web page with either a Flash player, or an HTML5 player, or a native iOS app with the native player.

While the video is playing, is it possible to grab a frame from the video and send it back to the server?

### For example:

## Flash

So, in the player, there's an RTMP or HDS streaming coming in. Using ActionScript is it even possible to grab frames from the stream the player is playing?

## HTML5

This I imagine the answer is no, as all I have it javascript and the DOM, but do any implementation of the video tag allow for this type of interactivity? If so, which ones? I'm really only interested in iOS Safari and Android 3+ as the stream would be HLS.

## Native iOS

Similarly to the Flash solution, does Apple provide the APIs in iOS that would allow me, in an app, to capture frames from an HLS stream?

Comment: For HTML5, you should be able to use a canvas to capture an image of a video element.  [Relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5372501/168868).

Comment: Hey charles, thanks so much! why not post this as a possible answer? It certainly helps!. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to take video as data URI

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width = $('#video').outerWidth();
var height = $('#video').outerHeight();
canvas.width = width;  canvas.height = height;
var videoElem = document.getElementById('video');
context.drawImage(videoElem, 0, 0, width, height);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
console.log(dataURL);
```