# HTML5 Capture image of paused video stream and save it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html5 webpage and on there I want to provide a stream. This works so far with the following HTML code:

```
<video id="v" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="http://localhost:8080/stream.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

But now I want to provide the option that the user can pause the video and save the current seen picture  as jpeg file on the server.

But now I don't know how to get the image and save it a preferred location on the server. How can I save the current shown image as jpeg?

Comment: Similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5373155/3008050)

Comment: @karan3112 I tried this already, but it is not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
function capture() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  var video = document.getElementById("v");
  
  if (video.paused) {
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="v" autoplay="autoplay" >
    <source src="http://html5doctor.com/demos/video-canvas-magic/video.webm" type="video/ogg">
</video>
<input type="button" value="Capture" onclick="capture()"/>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

With the help from: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

To get the image on the canvas to an image file, you can use `canvas.toDataUrl` or `canvas.toDataUrlHD` (experimental). See the API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: canvas.drawImage causes the following error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function .

Comment: @IrgendwPointer: Sorry, my code has some errors. I have edited it and now you can get the video image to the canvas. From their saving to the file is easy.

Comment: Yeah now it works. Hopefully I'm able to store the image automatically.

Comment: One issue I am having with draw onto canvas is a mobile might be 360 pixel and a image with that res is not good enough. Need high res image from the video feed ?