# How to avoid tainted canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, canvas

I try to save an Canvas as an Image. But it fails always. I was looking up the Internet and Stackoverflow.com but I couldn't find the right answer.
I use the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970538/html5-capture-image-of-paused-video-stream-and-save-it) to get the context. This works fine, but if I use `context.toDataURL` I receive error **the Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.**

I do not understand why I get this until now, because I added to my canvas and to the videostream the attribute `crossorigin="anonymous"` and if I check the attribute in the javascript section I still receive that crossorigin is anonymous. Therefore it should work.

```
function captureimage(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var video = document.getElementById("v");
var ctx;
if(video.paused) {
    try {
         ctx = canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
     } catch (e) {
          alert(e);
     }
     var a = ctx.toDataURL();
}   
}
```

How can I solve this security issue? I also added `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` to my httpd.conf, but this didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it was solved by adding crossorigin="*" to the video tag

**Edit**: indeed, the correct way to do it is by setting `crossorigin="anonymous"`

Comment: "*" is not an valid value for this attribute. Any invalid value is treated as "anonymous". Therefore correct way of setting it would be crossorigin="anonymous"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when i was trying to draw an image that Chrome had cached into a canvas. I solved my issue by adding a unique cache breaking parameter to the image URL, to ensure that the image was never being cached.