# How to Make Save Button for Save Image on Video HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

in HTML5 Video, we can right click video and choose "Save image as..."

i want to make a button to automaticly save the image

please help, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Capture image of paused video stream and save it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970538/html5-capture-image-of-paused-video-stream-and-save-it)

Answer (score 0):

you need a `canvas` element which will get draw with the video data by using `drawImage(videoelement,0,0,videowidth,videoheigth)` (being the canvas as big as the video) and then use `canvas.toDataURL();` which will give you a base64 png image of the frame in the canvas then convert the data to a `blob` so you can save it then you just need to make the blob a url and by opening the url it shall be saved

Example

```js
var v = document.getElementById("video1");
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var interval;

function canvasdrawvideo() {
  ctx.drawImage(v, 0, 0, 270, 135);
}

function savecanvasimage(fileName) {
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var data = atob(dataURL.substring("data:image/png;base64,".length)),
    asArray = new Uint8Array(data.length);
  for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
    asArray[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  var blob = new Blob([asArray.buffer], {
    type: "octet/stream"
  });

  var a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = "display: none";
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.href = url;
  a.download = fileName;
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

v.addEventListener("play", function() {
  interval = setInterval(canvasdrawvideo, 20);
});
v.addEventListener("pause", function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, false);
v.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, false);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>Video to use:</p>
  <video id="video1" controls width="270" autoplay>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.ogg" type='video/ogg' />
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.webm" type='video/webm' />
  </video>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="270" height="135" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
  <button onclick="savecanvasimage('image.png')">ScreenShot</button>
</body>

</html>
```

only problem is that the video must to be on the same server and the code needs to run on a server otherwise it gives error but it works perfectly in my apache server here